# Find which persion have all colorcodes using color table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL server. have two tables:

table1: persioncolors
table2: personcolors

how to find which persion have all colorcode using colors table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[colors](
    [colorcode] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersionColors](
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ColorCode] [varchar](50) NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[colors] ([colorcode]) VALUES (N'Red')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[colors] ([colorcode]) VALUES (N'Blue')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[colors] ([colorcode]) VALUES (N'Green')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Tom', N'Red')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Tom', N'Blue')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Tom', N'Green')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Tom', N'Brown')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Joe', N'Red')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Joe', N'Blue')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Joe', N'Green')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Hari', N'Red')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Hari', N'Blue')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Nani', N'Blue')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Test', N'Orange')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'Hari', N'ye')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'a', N'j')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'a', N'c')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'a', N't')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'a', N'u')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'b', N'u')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'b', N'i')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) VALUES (N'b', N'o')
```

Base on above two tables I want output like below :
    Name 
    Joe
    Tom
I tried like below:

```
select name  from  [dbo].[PersionColors] p
join colors c
on p.colorcode=c.colorcode 
group by name 
having (count(distinct p.colorcode ))=(select count(*)cnt from colors)
```

above query is giving the expeted result. but the query is taking more time while using distinct clause
in the above two tables have large data set(billions of records)

can you please tell me an alternative solution to achieve this task in SQL server

[image]

Comment: Tune the query!

Comment: Is there a `person` table?

Comment: Do your tables have any indexes? If not, there's one problem.

Comment: In sample 'distinct' is not needed, are there repetitions in real data per person? BTW all those "GO"s in code are unnecessary and would in fact slow down creating multiple batches.

Comment: The OP isn't questioning the speed of the `INSERT` statements in the sample DDL, @CetinBasoz. That data is there for our benefit.

Comment: @Larnu Who said that he was questioning it :)

Comment: I said you were *"BTW all those "GO"s in code are unnecessary and would in fact slow down creating multiple batches."* That aren't relevant to the performance question the OP is asking.

Comment: @Larnu, and I said "who said that he was questioning it". Reread the quote you provided, BTW stands for By The Way and it is there just as a side note. OP didn't seem to know that and would be a benefit for him to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Blind guess, maybe conditional aggregation, assuming you have a `Person` Table (which you should for normalised data)?

```
SELECT P.[Name]
FROM dbo.Person P
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Colors C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.PersonColors PC ON P.[Name] = PC.[Name] AND C.ColourCode = PC.ColourCode
GROUP BY P.[Name]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN PC.ColourCode IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

if you don't have a `Person` table, then I suggest creating one, to normalise your data.